# Android - Find Duplicate String at compile time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I have a 100's of string variable with different name, i don't want the developer to make mistake by adding different string name with same value
Example

```
val variable_1 = "some_value"
val variable_2 = "some_value"
```

In the above example both variable_1 and variable_2 has same value but different name, so for this i need to show some compile time error using some custom annotations
Is it possible with custom annotation ?, does anyone have any idea on this ?

Comment: Duplicate string in which scope ?  Please precise the requirement.

Comment: @davidxxx all variable declaration will be in a same kotlin file scope